# Weird behavior when concatenate string in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file store version information and I wrote a shell to read two fields and combine them. But when I concatenate those two fields, it show me a werid result.

version file:

```
buildVer = 3
version = 1.0.0
```

script looks like:

```
#!bin/bash

verFile='version'
sdk_ver=`cat $verFile | sed -nE 's/version = (.*)/\1/p'`
build_ver=`cat $verFile | sed -nE 's/buildVer = (.*)/\1/p'`
echo $sdk_ver
echo $build_ver
tagname="$sdk_ver.$build_ver"
echo $tagname
```

The output shows

```
1.0.0
3
.30.0
```

I tried to echo the sdk_ver directly without read it from file, this piece of script works well. So I think it may relate to the sed, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Does anyone know why it acts like that?

Comment: Not your main problem, but you have two examples of [useless use of cat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619430/253056) in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this problem because of presence of DOS line ending i.e. `\r` in each line of `version` file.

Use `dos2unix` or this `sed` command to remove `\r` first:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' version
```

btw you can also simplify your script using pure BASH constructs like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='= ' read -r k v; do
   declare $k="$v"
done < <(sed $'s/\r//' version)

tagname="$version.$buildVer"
echo "$tagname"
```

This will give output:

```
1.0.0.3
```

Comment: You are right, the version file is generated in Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution, with `awk`:

```
awk '/version/{v=$3} /buildVer/{b=$3} END{print v "." b}' version.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
buildVer = 3
version = 1.0.0

$ awk '/version/{v=$3} /buildVer/{b=$3} END{print v "." b}' file.txt 
1.0.0.3
```